# Accordion - Organized by Category and Group by States

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I have an html accordion with 3 types of categories (ACF custom field). `Refinanced`, `Refinanced with TIC`, and `Sold`. Each of the Categories have different post with their US States (ACF custom field). The problem here is whenever I post two different content with same State like, Texas, it creates 2 separate entries of Texas / Florida. I tried to google'd it but I can't seem to find the exact keyword to solve my issue. I tried `in_array` but no luck.

Here's the code. `$type` values: `['refinanced', 'refinanced with tic', 'sold']`

```
<?php 
    $loan_list = get_posts([
    'post_type' => [ 'nas-loanmaturity' ],
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'has_password' => false,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'loan_type',
    'meta_value' => $type,
]);

?>
<ul uk-accordion="active: 0">
    <?php foreach ( $loan_list as $loan ) : 
    $post_id = $loan->ID;
    $post_title = $loan->post_title;

    $category = get_field( 'lm_category', $post_id );
    $address = get_field( 'lm_address', $post_id );
    $state = get_field( 'lm_state', $post_id );
    $link = get_field( 'lm_link', $post_id );

    ?>
    <li>
        <a class="uk-accordion-title"><?php echo $state; ?></a>
        <div class="uk-accordion-content"> <!-- Content Goes Here --> </div>
    </li>
    <?php 

    endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Output is:

- California
- Florida
- Florida <-(this should be combined with the same state above)

Comment: The keyword would be _control break_. You need to compare the state of the current post with that of the previous one, and based on whether they are still the same or differ, you need to create output accordingly.

Comment: @CBroe I don't follow exactly the control break... I'm sorry about that. Another case that I am looking here is where will I need to compare the "state" so that I can categorized them in by group of State.